# What meaning red-green arrow in Class/Method in hint/search window?

Tags: intellij-idea

What meaning pr symbol red-green arrow in class/method searcher/hinter?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellij IDEA has a feature called [Machine-learning-assisted code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#ml_completion), which is intended to prioritize code completion suggestion based on the choices made by other local users in similar situation. Basically, if the IDE thinks a suggestion is getting more relevant for your situation, it will be moved higher up on the suggestion list and a green arrow will be shown. If the opposite happens, then red arrow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).